# C# Inserting a picture from a picturebox to mysql table(data type medium blob)

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, blob

Greetings everyone i am trying to insert an image from my C# form application to MySql table but i don't know how to deal with blob format help is apricated

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
           
            Con.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into ProductTable values('" + prodidTB.Text + "','" + bunifuPictureBox1.Image + "','" + suppliertxt.Text + "','" + prodnameTB.Text + "','" + prodqtyTB.Text + "','" + prodpriceTB.Text + "','" + proddescTB.Text + "','" + catcombo.SelectedValue.ToString() + "')", Con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Product Succesfully Added");
            Con.Close();
            populate();
            proddescTB.Text = "";
            prodidTB.Text = "";
            suppliertxt.Text = "";
            prodqtyTB.Text = "";
            prodnameTB.Text = "";
            prodpriceTB.Text = "";
            bunifuPictureBox1.Image = null;
            

            



        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
```

that's it for the code
The populate method i am using

```
void populate()
    {
        try
        {
            Con.Open();
            string Myquery = "select * from ProductTable";
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(Myquery, Con);
            MySqlCommandBuilder builder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(da);
            var ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            ProductsGv.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            DataGridViewImageColumn imageColumn = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
            imageColumn = (DataGridViewImageColumn)ProductsGv.Columns[1];
            imageColumn.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Stretch;
            ProductsGv.Columns[6].DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
            Con.Close();
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
```

that's it for the method populate

Comment: please use ***parameterised queries*** - building SQL queries by concatenation etc. is a recipe for disaster. not only is it a source for many hard to debug syntax errors, it's also a wide, open gate for ***[SQL Injection attacks](https://bobby-tables.com/)***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, you need to save the image from the `PictureBox` to the database.

If you are saving an image that was created in a `PictureBox` then use this:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
bunifuPictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp); // You can use other format
```

If the image in the `PictureBox` was loaded from a file, then:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
Image image = Image.FromFile("Image.jpg");  
image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

After that, in the insert query into the table, in place of the image parameter, use:

```
ms.ToArray()
```

And don't forget to `Close()` `MemoryStream` after insert.